Gitlab SSL certificate not trusted after renewal (SSL inspection)
I have renewed the self signed SSL certificate for the self hosted Gitlab instance and after renewal the certificate shows the new issued and expiration date.
The certs are added also at /etc/gitlab/trusted certs and still I have the error below.
It seems like a ssl-verification failure happens even after adding the CA to the ‘trusted-certs’-folder in the ‘/etc/gitlab’-volume.
it seems that the gitlab configuration skips the certificate-file.
Can someone assist me with this?
I tried to add the trusted certificates at /etc/gitlab volume but it didnt work

Since this is regarding server administration, this is a much better-suited question for Server Fault rather than Stack Overflow. Consider posting this there instead.
